# Is there any recommended JS library/framework to extract text from html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

We are recently working on the development of a crawler. One feature/function is to do transformation from crawled HTML into text. We have surveyed a few python solution such as [scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html). However, we decide to move coding language from python to nodejs. Is there any recommendation on exist JS framework/library to do the work to transform html into text? (e.g.: [html-to-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-text))

**Ps.** It will be great that the package itself can have some intelligence to remove the advertisement/footer/header out and easy to do extend if we want customized logic.

Many thanks!

Comment: SO is not the place for this question. You may have more chance looking at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (before asking there search their Q/As and read their [tour](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)).

Comment: PhantomJS, CasperJS, selenium-chrome

Comment: Hi  Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant, Many thanks for your comment, one component of our design is to use headless-chrome to crawl the page. And there seems to be a reader mode in chrome which we are trying to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So far, according to my survey, it seems that [readability](https://github.com/mozilla/readability) is possible one solution. With sample code below:

```
fs = require('fs')
var JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
var Readability = require('./Readability');
html = fs.readFileSync("/Users/librah/tmp/b.html")
var doc = new JSDOM(html.toString(), { url: "https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/Remove-the-edematousliterature-chrome-extension", });
reader = new Readability(doc.window.document);
article = reader.parse()
console.log(article.textContent.trim())
```